# Display "no records found" in webgrid c# web pages

Tags: c#, razor, webgrid, asp.net-webpages

Is there an easier way to display "No records found" in an empty webgrid? Below is the code I have that works for me. However, I do not want to have to create HTML table in the else block for other tabs.

```
@if (Page.Tab == "DisplayGrid")
{
    if (Page.IncompleteCount > 0)
    {
        var grid = new WebGrid(Page.DisplayData, rowsPerPage: 10, defaultSort: "UserName", canSort: true);
        @grid.Pager(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, previousText: "previous", nextText: "next", numericLinksCount: 20)
        @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("UserName", "User"),
            grid.Column("Column1", "Column 1", format: @<div><a href="@Href("~/thispage/", item.UserId)" target="_blank">@item.UserId</a></div>),
            grid.Column("Column2", "Column 2", format: @<div class="w400">@HH.TruncateString(@item.Column2, 125)</div>),
            grid.Column("Column3", "Column 3", format: @<div class="w200"> @HH.FmtDate(@item.Column3)</div>)),
                tableStyle: "simple", headerStyle: "hdr", rowStyle: "odd", alternatingRowStyle: "even", mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, previousText: "previous", nextText: "next", numericLinksCount: 20)
    }
   else
    { 
        <table>
            <tr bgcolor ="#336699">
                <td width="150">
                    <font color="white"><b><u>User</u></b></font>
                </td>
                <td width="100">
                    <font color="white"><b>Column 1</b></font>
                </td>
                <td width="300">
                    <font color="white"><b>Column 2</b></font>
                </td>
                <td width="100">
                    <font color="white"><b>Column 3</b></font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" align="center">
                    <br />
                    <b>No User Records Found</b>

             <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
}
```

Webgrid for other tabs have different columns and # of columns. It is tedious to make sure I have the correct colspan # so that the message of "No records found" is displayed properly (center aligned). Any easier way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: If you can add a footer, it'll do exactly what you want. In `@grid.Table()` it has an argument for that, but not `@grid.GetHtml()`. Then you can just use the value of `(Page.IncompleteCount > 0 ? Page.IncompleteCount : "No") + " User Record" + (Page.IncompleteCount == 1 ? : "s" : "") + " Found"` to always list the number of records found at the bottom (and it'll look like another row).

Comment: @grid.Table() method is what I was looking for. Now, I have to build paging because it doesn't have what the GetHtml() method offers (Paging features). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, Pluto.

Comment: Fantastic, I've never used WebGrid before so you should answer your own question and mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I figured it out. Thanks to Pluto for suggesting the grid.Table method:

```
{
        var grid = new WebGrid(Page.DisplayData, rowsPerPage: 10, defaultSort: "UserName", canSort: true);
        var tfooter = (Page.IncompleteCount > 0 ? Page.IncompleteCount : "No") + " User Record" + (Page.IncompleteCount == 1 ? Page.IncompleteCount : "s") + " Found";

    @grid.Pager(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, previousText: "previous", nextText: "next", numericLinksCount: 20)
    @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("UserName", "User"),
        grid.Column("Column1", "Column 1", format: @<div><a href="@Href("~/thispage/", item.UserId)" target="_blank">@item.UserId</a></div>),
        grid.Column("Column2", "Column 2", format: @<div class="w400">@HH.TruncateString(@item.Column2, 125)</div>),
        grid.Column("Column3", "Column 3", format: @<div class="w200"> @HH.FmtDate(@item.Column3)</div>)),
            tableStyle: "simple", headerStyle: "hdr", rowStyle: "odd", alternatingRowStyle: "even", footer: @<div><b>@tfooter</b></div>)
}
```

I couldn't use mode, previousText and nextText attributes in the grid.Table method. I found a reference on how to add paging to this method and I'm working on it.

Answer (score 0):

When you have no records, can you just display a div instead, like this?

```
@if (Page.Tab == "DisplayGrid")
{
    if (Page.IncompleteCount > 0)
    {
        var grid = new WebGrid(Page.DisplayData, rowsPerPage: 10, defaultSort: "UserName", canSort: true);
        @grid.Pager(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, previousText: "previous", nextText: "next", numericLinksCount: 20)
        @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("UserName", "User"),
            grid.Column("Column1", "Column 1", format: @<div><a href="@Href("~/thispage/", item.UserId)" target="_blank">@item.UserId</a></div>),
            grid.Column("Column2", "Column 2", format: @<div class="w400">@HH.TruncateString(@item.Column2, 125)</div>),
            grid.Column("Column3", "Column 3", format: @<div class="w200"> @HH.FmtDate(@item.Column3)</div>)),
                tableStyle: "simple", headerStyle: "hdr", rowStyle: "odd", alternatingRowStyle: "even", mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, previousText: "previous", nextText: "next", numericLinksCount: 20)
    }
   else
    { 
        <div><b>No User Records Found</b></div>
    }
}
```

Thanks for the feedback.  Do the headers get reused so they are the same every time? If so, you could assign your markup to a variable and use the @Html.Raw() helper to render that every time.

```
@{
    string noRecordsTable = "<table><tr> ...";
}
```

And then in your else condition:

```
@Html.Raw(noRecordsTable);
```

That's another alternative.  That way you're not writing the table over and over again in your Razor.

Comment: I'd like to be able to show column headers (Username, Column1, ...) and "No User Records Found" below these column headers.